# How to get value of nested class with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Hello i have problem i don't know how to get value of offer__name and offer_price.

```
<div class="offer">
  <div class="offer__name">
      <em> item1 </em>
      <em> description of item1 </em>
  </div>
  <div class="offer__price">500</div>
</div>

<div class="offer">
  <div class="offer__name">
      <em> item2 </em>
      <em> description of item2 </em>
  </div>
  <div class="offer__price">200</div>
</div>

<div class="offer">
  <div class="offer__name">
      <em> item3 </em>
      <em> description of item3 </em>
  </div>
  <div class="offer__price">100</div>
</div>
```

i try with

```
objects = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='offer']")));
for offer in objects:
    ...
```

but for-loop get me notice that object can't be iterated, can you help me?

I just want value like:
item1 description of item1 500, item2 description of item2 200, item3 description of item3 100,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple just grab the elements in list. You need `find_element`***s***`_*()` method to get list of elements where as you are using  -  `find_element_*()`
code for your reference -

```
lst_ele = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='offer']")
    for i in lst_ele:
        print(i.text)
```

Output -

[image]